# Cycles baking will not produce same colors

Tags: baking

I followed multiple different tutorials and help exactly, but the bake is always completely different, it is darker, different colors, single colored, shows ONE light spot, and looks like bad like single colored walls from the worst game.

.blend
[image]

Look:

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you using filmic ? 'cause you shouldn't when baking.

Comment: no I am not using filmic

Comment: Then I may have to make many guesses before we find the cause (if there's only one). Could you edit your question by including a link to your blend file uploaded from https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ?

Comment: Ok I added the blend file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Normals are flipped. In Edit Mode, select everything and go to Mesh > Normals > Flip Normals.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer.